# How to use entire row in select in function call?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm refactoring part of a humongous database package in Oracle PL/SQL, and there are many selects with very similar where-statements.

An example (made up, in reality 20 base comparisons, and another 5 or so depending on query):

```
-- Query 1
select * from data d into r_data
where 
   d.tm = time and
   d.per = period and
   d.mm = mm and
   d.br = br and
   d.ty = ty;

-- Query 2
select * from data d into r_data
where 
   d.tm = time and
   d.per = period and
   d.mm = mm and
   d.br = br and
   d.mat = mat;
```

As you can see, tm, per, mm and br are being compared in both cases, I thought this would be a smart solution:

```
-- A function for comparing rows
function are_similar(row1 in data%rowtype, row2 in data%rowtype)
 return number is
begin
 if row1.tm = row2.tm and
    row1.per = row2.per and
    row1.mm = row2.mm and
    row1.br = row2.br then
 then return 1;
 else return 0;
 end if;
end are_similar;

-- Query 1 (v_row is data%rowtype)
select * from data d into r_data
where 
   are_similar(d, v_row) = 1 and
   d.ty = v_row.ty;

-- Query 2 (v_row is data%rowtype)
select * from data d into r_data
where 
   are_similar(d, v_row) = 1 and
   d.mat = v_row.mat;
```

But I get:

```
Error(xxx,xxx): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "D": invalid identifier
```

I've tried googling for how to get the "row" out of the "row-identifier" (ie `D`) but I cannot find anything, and I've also found [How to pass an entire row (in SQL, not PL/SQL) to a stored function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585377/how-to-pass-an-entire-row-in-sql-not-pl-sql-to-a-stored-function) Which states what I'm trying to do might be impossible, is it? Or are there any ways of doing the same thing another way? IE getting rid of "where-clause duplication" because the code is really ugly and a hassle to maintain.

I know creating a new view with arguments would solve part of the issue, but if possible I would really like to keep the solution internal to the package I'm working with.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to send the entire row of a result set, that too with the `WHERE` clause. At-least in `SELECT` we can use `CURSORS` to be returned from SQL. You can send the PK value to the function, and do your comparison logic there, after querying the required columns.

Comment: First, though it may help readability, creating a function to check the first four rows for equality probably did not speed you query up very much since you are running through the same table a bunch of times. Have you considered changing your where clause to be `Where d.time = time and ... and d.br = br and (d.ty = ty or d.mat = mat); Second, currently you are trying to pass the whole table.

Comment: @Jenn I am not looking to speed up the query at all, the queries are run once per day, the only thing of essence is readability and maintainability. Actually, it's not the table itself, it's the placeholder for the row-"struct" (I do not know the internal representations here).

Comment: @OracleUser But still you cannot chain queries on cursors =/ PK to function would have been a good idea, wouldn't help readability since the PK is a combination of 20 fields. I know the db-model is utter crap, but it was created roughly 20 years ago, and everything I want to do is make querying a bit easier.

Comment: @flindeberg how about rowids, if not PK ?

Comment: @OracleUser Hms, I don't know enough about oracle to answer that, I guess I have to google it. Got any suggested literature on the topic?

Comment: rowid will really help you in this situation. It is just an internal representation pointer for a row unique across the database. You can just select rowid from urtAble and check the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone familiar with OO techniques can see what you're trying to do. You've identified common code and are trying to refactor that into a separate module.

You're working in a different environment when you're working in SQL. What is considered clever in other languages is, well, not so very clever in SQL. And vice versa if it makes you feel any better. In languages such as Java, C#, C++ or any other language specifically designed for the OO environment, we can lean more heavily toward maintainability rather than performance because the cost is so low.

Not so in SQL. Everything takes at least 10 times longer to perform in SQL as any other language. Reworking a query to have it call a function where it did not before will decrease the responsiveness of the query noticeably. It can turn a 5 msec query into a 45 sec query or even worse. Even a 5 sec query is simply not acceptable.

One thing that you have to be aware of in SQL but not in other languages is context switching. This is where you go from SQL to the wrapper language vendors place around their system's SQL. This is PL/SQL in Oracle or Transact-SQL in SQL Server. Every system has one. A query is SQL. That is one context. The body of a stored procedure is the wrapper language. That is another context. Calling a stored procedure involves more than executing code over *here* to executing code over *there*. Switching contexts back and forth can be very time consuming. The details differ between systems so you should become familiar with your system's specifics.

Another difference is that other languages are procedural in nature. You identify what they have to do, then define step by step how to do it. In SQL, you identify what data you want. While there are ways to have *some* influence, by and large the underlying system determines how to go about doing it.

There are many techniques for writing good, responsive SQL code. Rewriting a query to call a stored procedure for every row is not one of them.

Comment: But there are pragmas and the like which limits function references etc, but what you are saying it that there is no way to inline a function call anyhow? Do I understand you correctly? SQL is and always will be a hassle to maintain?

Comment: If there is no way to inline a function, then this entire conversation would be a waste of time. There are data manipulations and calculations that just can't be done in SQL. For those, the choice is either develop a function callable by SQL or pass the raw data to the app and let it do the processing. Actually, unless there is a compelling reason otherwise, I lean toward the latter.

Comment: Whether or not SQL is a hassle to maintain depends on what you expect from it. It is not Object Oriented so if you expect it to conform to OO techniques, then, yes, it will be a hassle. If you work with it rather than fight it, not so much. SQL is rather unique. Learn to appreciate it.